# How to fix org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I'm working with an **OSGi BundleActivator** code. When I'm trying to install it using **Apache Karaf** I always get a `Unable to install bundle mvn:com.baeldung/osgi-intro-sample-activator/1.0-SNAPSHOT: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: mvn:com.baeldung/osgi-intro-sample-activator/1.0-SNAPSHOT` error.

The tutorial I tried to follow is here: https://www.baeldung.com/osgi

The command I use is `bundle:install mvn:com.baeldung/osgi-intro-sample-activator/1.0-SNAPSHOT`. Tried to add -s flag or use `install` instead of `bundle:install`, didn't help. Tried to run it from the Karaf root and bundle directory, didn't help.

In a Karaf folder I tried to set `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository=/Users/bogdansalyp/.m2/repository`, didn't help.

Emptied `.m2/repository`, didn't help. Copied it to the bundle and Karaf folders, didn't help.

Tried `mvn install` and `mvn clean install` from different directories, didn't help.

Karaf is v4.2.6, maven is 3.1.1

Here's my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>osgi-intro-sample-activator</artifactId>
    <name>osgi-intro-sample-activator</name>
    <!-- Please, note this is not the usual 'jar'. -->
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <!-- com.baeldung/osgi-intro-sample-activator/1.0-SNAPSHOT -->
    <parent>
        <artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>

                        <!-- Qualified name of the class that exposes the activator iface. -->
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.baeldung.osgi.sample.activator.HelloWorld</Bundle-Activator>

                        <!-- One important thing to note: since you are not exporting the package "com.baeldung.osgi.sample.activator", you should at least add it to the Private-Package
                            instruction. Otherwise, the classes inside the package will not be copied to your bundle, as the default value of this instruction is empty. -->

                        <Private-Package>com.baeldung.osgi.sample.activator</Private-Package>

                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here's the Java code I use:

```java
package com.baeldung.osgi.sample.activator;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class HelloWorld implements BundleActivator {

    public void start(BundleContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("Hello World.");
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye World.");
    }

}
```

The code structure can be found here: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/osgi/osgi-intro-sample-activator

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You should replace with `bundle:install mvn:com.baeldung/osgi-intro-sample-activator/1.0-SNAPSHOT` to `bundle:install mvn:com.baeldung/osgi/1.0-SNAPSHOT` because your artifactId is osgi. Keep following this link

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I used Karaf but I have few thoughts.

IIRC the "org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle" actually means that what Karaf is getting form the provided URL is not an installable bundle. So

- make sure you have run `mvn install` (`mvn package` is not enough) to install the bundle in your local Maven repo **before** you try to install it in Karaf.
- try changing the version form `1.0-SHAPSHOT` to `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. Not sure if that is related but in general try to have [semantic versions](https://www.osgi.org/developer/white-papers/semantic-versioning/semantic-versions/)
- try using `bundle:watch` instead of `bundle:install` ([see the docs](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_watch)) which will also automatically update the bundle when you reinstall it to local Maven repo.

I vaguely remember having some issues with `bundle:install` and SNAPSHOT bundles and/or local Maven repository but sadly no details. One thing to check is that your [Maven repos and setting](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_maven_configuration_commands) are correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the activator should be not be located in the private package, it should be public.

Probably, this is the culprit:

```
<Private-Package>com.baeldung.osgi.sample.activator</Private-Package>
```

Remove it.

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't change the situation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little to late, but the error says that karaf can not find the bundle. Check the file location in .m2 or the if the generated MANIFEST is correct.
Best luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know you've mentioned that it didn't help you, but it worked for me and might be helpful for others to set the property `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository=` located in
`<KARAF_HOME>/etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` file.